# datetime goes one hour forward when using unix timestamp with localtime settings

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, unix-timestamp

Firstly i want to tell my server time setting : its **+3 Europe/Istanbul**
and in php i am using

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
```

I use datetime type in my mysql table, when i insert row, its written like **2011-10-01 15:16:09** its correct no problem but in php side when i query and echo date time with
`echo strftime("%d %b %Y, %a %H:%M",strtotime(date("m/d/Y H:i",$data['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)'])));`
i get time one hour forward like **16:16:09**

i dont understand how to figure it out. Any idea ?

**Edit :** 
when inserting the rows i give the date to mysql, it doesnt use internal date info like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: What value is in `$data['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)']`? `1317471369`?

Comment: yes @salathe its like 1317471369 Mysql convert datetime to timestamp format so i use it in php date function to creat that date and time.But somehow it gives one hour forward

Comment: but is it **like** 1317471369 or is it actually 1317471369 ?

Comment: Also, why do you go from unix timestamp, to formatted date, to unix timestamp, to formatted date? Why not just `strftime("…", $data[…])`?

Comment: @salathe you are right. Firstly i was going to do that like your suggestion but i didnt want to struggle with exploding date time to format that i need to :) Sometimes the first comes to mind is correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly due to daylight savings times. If one part of the code specifies +3, that's already corrected for daylight savings. If the other part of the code doesn't recognize the date as already correct for daylight savings time, it will add an hour.

I know it's not a great answer, but I don't seem to be able to post a comment yet.